# System.Threading.Timer

Tags: .net, windows, service, visual-c++

I am new to VC++ .net programming. Please help me out how to use System.Threading.Timer in a windows service VC++ .net code. I tried using form.timer and system.timer class but as it turns out it's a known windows bug and it won't work reliably. I am not able to use system.threading.timers. Please give an example.

Nitin

Comment: Did you google for "System.Threading.Timer" before posting your question? The first result is the MSDN page for the timer with good examples.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I did google. Please see my response below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As AndrewS mentioned, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx) usually has good starter examples.  You can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) out and scroll down to the Examples section under the Visual C++ section to see the System.Threading.Timer example.

Comment: Yes I googled and that too a LOT. OK I delve out the issues. The Timer class by Microsoft has issues and is a known MS bug http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842793

Microsoft suggests using System.threading.timer instead of System.Timer.Timer (wrapper class) or System.Forms.Timer(doesn't work for windows services). However, I am not able to use System.Threading.Timer in VC++ .net, not sure what I am not doing wrong (I used MSDN examples for help) but it just doesn't work. System.Timer.timer class was unreliable but threading.timer doesn't even work for me. So I wanted some working examples.

Comment: The examples supplied on the MSDN page will work.  You should post your code that doesnt work s0 we can figure out whats wrong with it.